# play-framework [2.0] won't load project definitions

Tags: playframework-2.0

I just download the Play-Framework 2.0 and i'm trying to create a new project. Fine till here but as soon as I enter the folder and type the command play in the command line it wont get passed the "Loading project definitions form"

here's what i see on my console:

```
D:\Play tests\test2>play
Getting org.scala-tools.sbt sbt_2.9.1 0.11.2 ...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-tools.sbt#boot-app
        confs: [default]
        37 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (7324kB/204ms)
[info] Loading project definition from D:\Play tests\test2\project
```

i can't find anyone with the same problem.

i'm have windows 7, java jdk1.7.0_03 and i've used play-framework 1.2.4 (i've changed the path to the 2.0 version)

Comment: You should type that as an answer and accept it so people know this question is solved.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Windows 7, JDR 1.7.0_05, Play Framework 2.0.2. No firewall blocking anything

Comment: my problem wasn't the firewall it was the schools internet blocking the access. I changed the connection to a internet mobile device i own.(I beleave the school has that to try and prevent piracy, no idea)

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373536/play-framework-hangs-on-startup-at-loading-project-definition-from

Comment: @oncereply ty for replaying but this problem has been resolved for a long time now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem, it appears that if play-framework tryed to download a file and was unable to get it and wouldn't timeout. The problem in my case was that i'm at my college's department and for some reason it was blocking the connection. I changed my connection to the wireless connection and its all fine now.

Ty for the help anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try with jdk 1.6. I´m using it and it´s working great.

Comment: that would be weird because they say it's supported and my college is also using 1.7 and it's working without any problems