# Play (Java) hangs when loading project definition after upgrading to 2.2.2

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

I've just upgraded from Play 2.2.0 to 2.2.2. After doing so running any play command from my project results in it hanging while loading the project definition. After viewing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373536/play-framework-hangs-on-startup-at-loading-project-definition-from) question, I set my `logLevel` to `Debug` to see where it was hanging. It always appears to hang at this stage:

`[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#routes-compiler_2.10;2.2.2 ...
[debug] sbt-chain: Checking cache for: dependency: com.typesafe.play#routes-compiler_2.10;2.2.2 {compile=[default(compile)]}
[debug]         tried http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/routes-compiler_2.10/2.2.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[debug] CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/routes-compiler_2.10/2.2.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[debug]     typesafe-ivy-releases: no ivy file found for com.typesafe.play#routes-compiler_2.10;2.2.2
[debug]         tried http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/routes-compiler_2.10/2.2.2/ivys/ivy.xml`

The error messages seem correct, as following those URL's gives me a `not found` error.

As a sanity check, I've also tried creating a brand new Java project with play an got exactly the same behaviour. Has anyone else experienced this?

For reference, this is my build.sbt file:

```
name := "appname"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4",
  "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.3.2",
  "commons-codec" % "commons-codec" % "1.9",
  "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "15.0",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-jdbc" % "2.2.0" exclude("com.jolbox", "bonecp"),
  "com.jolbox" % "bonecp" % "0.8.0.RELEASE"
)     

play.Project.playJavaSettings
```

My build.properties file:

`sbt.version=0.13.0`

and my plugins.sbt file:

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Debug

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.2")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, it turned out that what was actually happening was that Play appeared to be timing out (extremely slowly) downloading various .jar files from http://repo.typesafe.com/

Manually downloading the files via my browser and placing them in the relevant folder in

`$play/repository/cache`

seems to have solved the issue for me.

Comment: Or, in my case, "More patience"

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it is due to the play(the bin tool) version is not same as the sbt version defined in `project/plugins.sbt`. And play acutually prints this warnning. So make sure these two versions are same first.

[image]