# Import of new play projects into IDEA via build.sbt hangs

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

I'm using the current release of the Play framework. After having created a new project via `activator new foobar`, I tried to import it into IntelliJ IDEA (with installed Scala plugin) by importing the project's build.sbt file.

IDEA/SBT then downloads the dependencies but is always stuck here (even after hours nothing happens):

```
SBT: [info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalaz/scalaz-core...
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have not personally experienced that kind of hanging behavior, but here are a couple of thoughts. (1) I see that this library is about 1MB (not sure on the exact version, but picked a recent one: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalaz/scalaz-effect_2.11/7.1.0/). Are you on an unusually slow connection?  Others have reported the hanging when downloads are slowly taking place. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12605068/2308858.  (2) You can try clearing your `~/.ivy2/cache folder` (this has fixed things for me before). If on Windows look for `.ivy2/cache` near your home folder.

Comment: Thanks, it finally worked. I just waited another hour. My connection does 25mbit/s, but the download took very long. Maybe problems with the server and its bandwidth capacity (although the manual download is fast). If you want, you can add an answer.

Comment: Thanks, added an answer with some additional details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not personally experienced that kind of hanging behavior, but here are a couple of thoughts.

1. I see that this library is about 1MB. (I'm not sure on the exact version, but I picked a recent one: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalaz/scalaz-effect_2.11/7.1.0). Are you on an unusually slow connection? Others have reported the hanging when downloads are slowly taking place. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12605068/2308858.
2. You can try clearing your `~/.ivy2/cache` folder (this has fixed things for me before). If on Windows look for `.ivy2/cache` near your home folder.

I've noticed that sometimes SBT does not give insight into what it's doing, often because it is suppressing otherwise helpful output.  Check out http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Howto/logging.html for some options on how to see more details or change the logging level.

**Update:** See second comment on original question for additional details.